# How to get GUI elements to update on loading ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, swing, objectinputstream

I am programming a board game and I am trying to add save/load functionality.  I have been going about this by using FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream.  I think the load functionality is working properly but the visual GUI elements are not updating such as player position.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this such as calling repaint() or something?  I tried this but it could not be recognized. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
package worldofsweets;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class WorldOfSweets {

  public static int currentPlayer = 0;
  public static int maxPlayers = 0;
    private Deck cardDeck;
    private TurnIndicator turn;
    private Board gameBoard;
    private PlayerChooser playerChooser;
    private JLabel numPlayers;
    private boolean turnActive = true;
    private StartButton start;
    private DiscardPile discard;
    public WorldOfSweets() {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("World Of Sweets");
        gameFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 1000, 800);

        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(gameFrame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        Object[] options = {"New Game",
                    "Load Game"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(gameFrame,
            "Would you like to start a new game or load a previous game?",
            "World Of Sweets",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]);
        if(n==1){
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

            int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                loadGame(selectedFile);

            }
        } else {
            playerChooser = new PlayerChooser();
            gameBoard = new Board(playerChooser.getPlayerNames());
            discard = new DiscardPile();
            cardDeck = new Deck(discard);
        }

        JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();
        boardPanel.add(gameBoard);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
        JPanel textUpdate = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));

        turn = new TurnIndicator();

        start = new StartButton(true);

        cardDeck.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card currCard = cardDeck.draw();
            Color newSpace = currCard.getColor();

            if (currCard.getType() == "1") {
                gameBoard.move(newSpace, currentPlayer);
            }

            else if (currCard.getType() == "2") {
                gameBoard.move(newSpace, currentPlayer);
                gameBoard.move(newSpace, currentPlayer);
            }

            else if (currCard.getType() == "M") {
                gameBoard.move(newSpace, currentPlayer);
            }

            //cardDeck.setBackground(newSpace);
            disableButton(cardDeck);
            enableButton(start);
            }
        });


        numPlayers = new JLabel("# players");

        cardDeck.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 300));
        discard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,300));

        JButton saveLoad = new JButton("Save/Load");
        saveLoad.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

            int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                saveGame(selectedFile, gameBoard, cardDeck, discard, playerChooser);
                }

            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(saveLoad);
        //buttonPanel.add(cardType);
        buttonPanel.add(cardDeck);
        buttonPanel.add(discard);
        buttonPanel.add(start);
        buttonPanel.add(turn);
        buttonPanel.add(numPlayers);


        gameFrame.setLayout(boxLayout);
        gameFrame.add(gameBoard);
        gameFrame.add(buttonPanel);
        //gameFrame.add(discard);

        gameFrame.setVisible(true);


        numPlayers.setText("# players: " + playerChooser.getNumPlayers());

        maxPlayers = playerChooser.getNumPlayers();

        turn.changeTurn(playerChooser.getPlayerNames()[0]);
        currentPlayer = 1;
        disableButton(start);

        start.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (turnActive)
                {
                    turnActive = false;
                    start.flipButton(turnActive);
                    if (gameBoard.playerWin(currentPlayer) == true)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("currPlayer:" + currentPlayer);
                        turn.setText(playerChooser.getPlayerNames()[currentPlayer-1] + " wins!");
                        numPlayers.setText("");
                        disableButton(cardDeck);
                        disableButton(start);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setNextPlayer();
                        turn.changeTurn(playerChooser.getPlayerNames()[currentPlayer-1]);
                    }
                }

                else if (!turnActive)
                {
                    turnActive = true;
                    start.flipButton(turnActive);
                    enableButton(cardDeck);
                    disableButton(start);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorldOfSweets game = new WorldOfSweets();
    }

  public void setNextPlayer() {
    if (currentPlayer == maxPlayers)
      currentPlayer = 1;
    else
      currentPlayer++;
  }

  public void disableButton (JButton btn) {
    btn.setBorderPainted( false );
    btn.setFocusPainted( false );
    btn.setEnabled( false );
  }

  public void enableButton (JButton btn) {
    btn.setBorderPainted( true );
    btn.setFocusPainted( true );
    btn.setEnabled( true );
  }

  public void saveGame(File file, Board b, Deck d, DiscardPile dp, PlayerChooser p) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(b);
        oos.writeObject(d);
        oos.writeObject(dp);
        oos.writeObject(p);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception save ");
    }
  }

  public void loadGame(File file) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        gameBoard = (Board) ois.readObject();
        //int[] playerPos = (int[]) ois.readObject();
        //String[] playerNames = (String[]) ois.readObject();
        cardDeck = (Deck) ois.readObject();
        discard = (DiscardPile) ois.readObject();
        playerChooser = (PlayerChooser) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception load");
    }
}

}
```